# Column names don't match table using SELECT variables as INSERT values

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, if-statement, select, where-clause

I created a stored procedure that would INSERT/UPDATE when necessary. I am using this method to evaluate if i have to insert or not:

```
INSERT INTO X
SELECT @A, @B, @C -- Exactly as the table, all nullables
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * from ... WHERE condition)
```

But i am receiving the

> Msg 213, Level 16, State 1, Procedure ArtigoEAN_Remover, Line 48 [Batch Start Line 7]
>   Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.

This is my complete code (i signaled *line 48*):

```
@ArtigoID AS varchar(14),
@TipoArtigo AS varchar(3),
@CodBarras AS varchar(24)

AS
BEGIN
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from interfering with SELECT statements.
SET NOCOUNT ON;

    IF (@ArtigoID IS NOT NULL AND @TipoArtigo IS NULL) OR (@ArtigoID IS NULL AND @TipoArtigo IS NOT NULL)
    BEGIN
        PRINT 'Tem que escolher ArtigoID & TipoArtigo para remover código EAN da referência.'
        RETURN
    END
    --
    IF (@CodBarras IS NOT NULL) AND (@ArtigoID IS NOT NULL OR @TipoArtigo IS NOT NULL)
    BEGIN
        PRINT 'Escolher Código EAN apenas (Para remover esse código de barras de todas as referências) OU ArtigoID + TipoArtigo (remover todos os códigos EAN associados a essa referência)'
        RETURN
    END
    --
    IF @ArtigoID IS NOT NULL AND @TipoArtigo IS NOT NULL 
    BEGIN 

    UPDATE [s].[dbo].[FArtigo]
    SET CodBarras = ''
    WHERE ArtigoID = @ArtigoID AND TipoArtigo = @TipoArtigo AND CodBarras = @CodBarras
    -- LINE 48
    INSERT INTO [s].[dbo].[Infolog_ArtigoEAN] 
    SELECT @ArtigoID,@TipoArtigo,@CodBarras
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM [s].[dbo].[Infolog_ArtigoEAN] WHERE ArtigoID = @ArtigoID AND TipoArtigo = @TipoArtigo AND CodBarras = @CodBarras)
    -- Inserts above if nox exist, update below in any case.
    UPDATE [s].[dbo].[Infolog_ArtigoEAN] SET CodBarras = '' WHERE ArtigoID = @ArtigoID AND TipoArtigo = @TipoArtigo AND CodBarras = @CodBarras

    INSERT INTO [s].[dbo].[ArtigoEAN]
    SELECT @ArtigoID,@TipoArtigo,@CodBarras
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM [s].[dbo].[Infolog_ArtigoEAN] WHERE ArtigoID = @ArtigoID AND TipoArtigo = @TipoArtigo AND CodBarras = @CodBarras)
    UPDATE [s].[dbo].[ArtigoEAN] SET CodBarras = '' WHERE ArtigoID = @ArtigoID AND TipoArtigo = @TipoArtigo AND CodBarras = @CodBarras

    END
    --
    IF @CodBarras IS NOT NULL AND (@ArtigoID IS NULL AND @TipoArtigo IS NULL) 
    BEGIN

    UPDATE [s].[dbo].[FArtigo] SET CodBarras = '' WHERE CodBarras = @CodBarras
    UPDATE [s].[dbo].[Infolog_ArtigoEAN] SET CodBarras = '' WHERE CodBarras = @CodBarras
    UPDATE [s].[dbo].[ArtigoEAN] SET CodBarras = '' WHERE CodBarras = @CodBarras

    END
END
```

So my question is, why is it trying to do the INSERT after line 48 when i am just ALTERING (saving) the procedure, i'm not even running it with parameters.

Keep in mind that i want to INSERT using the SELECT as condition (INSERT INTO dbo.Example SELECT (to,insert,if,true) WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dbo.Example WHERE myCondition = notExist)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting this error because the number of columns in your table and the number of values that you have specified in the insert statement does not match.

In your query, you have provided 3 values, So It is possible that in your table either there are more than 3 columns or less than 3 columns.

To avoid such error in future, Instead of specifying

```
INSERT INTO TableName
VALUES(1,2,3)
```

Specify the Column names to which y want to insert the values. Like this

```
INSERT INTO TableName(Col1,Col2,Col3)
VALUES(1,2,3)
```

or

```
INSERT INTO X(Col1,Col2,Col3)
SELECT @A, @B, @C
```

You don't need to run the Script / Procedure to get the error, SQL Server will return the error on Compilation time ie; when you try to create or alter a procedure

Comment: Well but i only want to insert IF a condition is true. Should i put the SELECT inside VALUES? See my edited question (the final part)

Comment: I have added one sample for select

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion and the explanation.